# The easiest way to run java class when editing the .java file form VIM

Tags: java, vim, terminal

If I'm coding in cpp, in Vim I can do:

```
!g++ % && ./a.out
```

to quickly compile and run the code.

However, if I'm coding in Java, in Vim I can do:

```
!javac %
```

for a quick compilation, but for running the java class, I cannot do:

```
!java %
```

because I need to put the class name only (without the trailing .java suffix)

Is there a quick way in VIM to do what I did when I was coding in Cpp?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Just about no useful java programs fit into one class.

Comment: `!java %:r`  may work

Comment: @bmargulies I want to quickly compile&test my java program.. Usually I made it quite small like to be fitting in 1 file

Comment: @rbernabe what does %:r means? and it works, thx ~:)

Comment: Use Eclipse or IntelliJ, not vim, if you want to develop java quickly.

Comment: @bmargulies Yeah I know IDE is great... but it's also too large to load. Sometimes I just want to quickly verify some code so just use Vim:)

Comment: @songyy :h expand says
:r  root (one extension removed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim has modifiers with which you can manipulate filenames. For your use case, the `:r` modifier returns the *root*, i.e. the file name with the last extension removed:

```
:!java %:r
```

See the full list at `:help filename-modifiers`; they also can be combined. Note that for more complex builds, a Java build solution like *Ant* or *Maven* is probably more effective; these can also be launched from Vim; even integrated into its `:make` command.